# Overriding convenience init

Tags: swift

Trying to subclass an NSTextView:

```
class MYTextView : NSTextView {
    init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        setup()
    }
}
```

I get this error: `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSTextView'` on this line: `super.init(frame: frameRect)`.

According to the docs `Convenience initializers must call another initializer available in the same class.`. See 'Initializer Chaining' below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_286

But for NSTextViews the only designated inits i get are `super.init(frame:, textContainer:)` & `super.init(coder: coder)` & `super.inti()`.  `init(frame:)` does some setup which I'd rather not implement myself.

Is there some way to use a super class's convenience initializer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the designated initialisers:

```
class MyTextView : NSTextView {

    init(frame frameRect: NSRect, textContainer aTextContainer: NSTextContainer!) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect, textContainer: aTextContainer)

        setup();
    }

    func setup() {
         ...       
    }
}

var textView = MyTextView(frame: NSRect())
```

Since all the designated initialisers are overridden, all convenience will be automatically inherited.

There are two other designated initialzers to override:

```
init() {
}
```

and

```
init(coder:) {
}
```

Comment: NSTextView actually has `init()` and `init(coder:)` that need to be overridden to inherit the convenience inits.

Comment: @AlexMarchant Had to look it up. `init(coder:)` is not designated, it actually comes from a protocol (`NSCoding`).

Comment: I guess that still counts though, try these out in the Playground. With `init(frame:,textContainer:)` there is an error https://gist.github.com/alexmarchant/3fd270471920af517908. Add in `init()` still error https://gist.github.com/alexmarchant/78dd4654115cad7c67b7. But with all three it works https://gist.github.com/alexmarchant/d3dbe45563386db18ec6.

Answer (score 2):

I was just tripped up by this exact problem as well. I still find Swift initialization with inheritance tricky, so definitely possible I'm not understanding something else here.

The accepted answer seems to suggest overriding `init(frame: textContainer:)`, `init`, and `init(coder:)` will make `init(frame:)` accessible, but it does not for me.

The only way I was able to get things working as I wanted was with this:

```
override init(frame frameRect: NSRect, textContainer container: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect, textContainer: container)

    setup()
}

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    // this will end up calling init(frame:textContainer:)
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```