# Initialize subclass of NSTextView without providing NSTextContainer

Tags: swift, initialization, designated-initializer, convenience-methods

I have a subclass of `NSTextView`, and in my initializer of this subclass I would like to call:

```
super.init(frame: NSMakeRect(...))
```

which is what I always do when initializing an `NSTextView` programmatically. I simply write:

```
let textView = NSTextView(frame: NSMakeRect(0,0,10,10))
```

However, when I do this in my subclass (`super.init(frame: (...))`), the compiler throws an error. It won't let me use `init(frame:)` because `init(frame:)` is a convenience initializer of `NSTextView`, and I must call "a designated initializer of the superclass." 
After checking the documentation, I found out that the designated initializer of `NSTextView` is `init(frame: textContainer:)` but I don't want to deal with `NSTextContainers`. Why is it that I must call a designated initializer from a subclass of an object, but I can call a convenience initializer  if the object is not being subclassed? Whenever I usually initialize an `NSTextView` I don't have to provide an `NSTextContainer`, but when I initialize an `NSTextView` as the superclass of a subclass, I do. Why is this?

Also, is there any way of initializing an `NSTextView` with a sort of "default" text container? Regardless of designated initializers, all I want to do here is to create an `NSTextView` without worrying about `NSTextContainers`.

Comment: I just ran into a very similar issue. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/44025300/288405.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a work a round for this. It's not pretty, but it gets the job done. Basically I'm just creating an instance of `NSTextView` inside of my subclass initializer using `init(frame:)` and then applying the resulting `textContainer` to `super`:

```
class Header: NSTextView {

    // methods and properties...

    init(frame theFrame: NSRect) {
        // using desired convenience initializer
        let test = NSTextView(frame: theFrame) 

        // using designated initializer, as required by the compiler
        super.init(frame: test.frame, textContainer: test.textContainer) 
    }

}
```